# Quotients of spaces onto spaces with smaller weight

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space of weight $\kappa$. Is it possible to find for every infinite cardinal $\lambda <\kappa$ a compact Hausdorff space $L$ of weight $\lambda$ and a continuous surjection $f\colon K\to L$?

I think I can do it for $\lambda=\aleph_0$ but my approach is very roundabout. Is it possible in general?

Comment: @EricWofsey, yes, now corrected.

Comment: how to delete this

Comment: @WilliamElliot On a computer mouse over it. You'll get an edit and cross on the right.

Comment: @bof, isn't it the same?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma.  Do what with a mouse?  What if I do not have a mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy if you only want weight $\le \lambda$:

$X$ can be embedded into $[0,1]^\kappa$ (as a closed subset), via $e:K \to [0,1]^\kappa$, the standard embedding (from being Tychonoff).

Then define $\pi_\lambda: [0,1]^\kappa \to [0,1]^\lambda$ by restricting maps $f: \kappa \to [0,1]$ to $\lambda \subset \kappa$. Then $\pi_\lambda \circ e$ maps $K$ onto a compact space of weight at most $\lambda$, as $w([0,1]^\lambda) = \lambda$.

Of course you can take any subset $A \subseteq \kappa$ with $|A|  =\lambda$ and the projection $\pi_A$ (restriction to those coordinates). For $\lambda = \aleph_0$ we are done, we just have to make sure the image is infinite.

Intuitively, if $w(X) = \kappa$ there should be some $A$ with $\pi_A \circ e[K]$ of weight exactly $\lambda$. Maybe this gives you an idea?